# Having With Sub query MySql

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, max, having-clause

I want to select  which model car is involved in most accidents.
i am using the following query but i get a syntax error.
please someone tell me whats wrong..

```
    select car.Model 
    from car 
    join car_accident_involved 
       on car.Car_Registration_ID = car_accident_involved.Car_Registration_ID 
    group by car.Model 
    having MAX(
       select COUNT(Car_Registration_ID) 
       from car_accident_involved
    );
```

Comment: Do you want to know what's causing the syntax error, or what's wrong with the query?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple sub query here, e.g:

```
select model from car
where car_registration_id = 
 (select car_registration_id
  from car_accident_involved
  group by model 
  order by count(car_registration_id) desc
  limit 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

HAVING is a condition statement for GROUP BY. Your query hasn't any condition in
 HAVING statement,so error arises.
A for me, there is no need in subquery. Try more simple query like:

```
SELECT c.model,COUNT(a.car_registration_id) AS Num_of_accidents FROM car c   
INNER JOIN car_accident_involved a ON c.car_registration_id=a.car_registration_id  
GROUP BY c.model ORDER BY Num_of_accidents DESC LIMIT 1;
```